# undoing javascript animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am making the div of a carousel larger on a certain pane. To enlarge the pane I do:

```
if(currentPane==2)
{
    $("#carousel").animate({height:320},1000);
    $("#carousel").animate({top:411},1000);
    $("#dropShadow").animate({top:731},1000);
}
```

This works perfectly well. When going off this pane I then want to return the carousel to a smaller size again, I do:

```
if(currentPane==3)
{
    $("#dropShadow").animate({top:672},1000);
    $("#carousel").animate({top:411},1000);
    $("#carousel").animate({height:100},1000);
}
```

the dropshadow returns to it's origional location but the carousel refuses to reduce in size.

to me it seems I am using the same code so don't see why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried adding a .stop()? such as:
just an idea not 100% sure, make jsfiddle

```
if(currentPane==3)
{
    $("#dropShadow").stop(true).animate({top:672},1000);
    $("#carousel").stop(true).animate({top:411},1000);
    $("#carousel").stop(true).animate({height:100},1000);
}
```

Comment: awesome! you might want to do an if else statement later on to have cleaner code